# Finding the area inside the rose

Tags: calculus, integration

Calculate the area inside the rose:$$r(\theta)=a\cos(n\theta)$$
where $n$ is a positive integer and $a$ a positive constant.
Why I'm making a mistake writing:$$A=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\,d\theta\int_{0}^{a\cos(\theta n)}r\,dr$$
?
I evaluated the integral above, it gives $A=a^2\pi/2$

which is exactly the area inside the rose when $n$ is even. But the area depends on whether $n$ is odd or even.

Comment: Whether the curve "double traces" itself depends on $n$ being odd or even. If it double traces, the integral you have will give t2ice the area.

Comment: Think about the domain of integration for $\theta$: should it always be $[0,2\pi]$? Hint: graph the rose for a few different $n$. How many petals does $n = 3$ have? How many for $n = 4$?

Comment: Why shouldn't it be always $[0,2\pi]$?